# disable per-column ordering in MYSQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I use MySQL workbench and get a huge dataset, i find it annoying that if I accidentally click on a row, workbench tries to order the data by that row - generally taking several minutes to complete.

I'm of the opinion that if I wanted a dataset ordered a particular way, I would have used an order-by clause.

Is there any way to disable the behavior of ordering a dataset by clicking on a particular column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I think you're out of luck in this regard, unless of course you download the source code for MySQL Workbench and change the way the UI behaves and add in an option to disable column ordering on click.

Source is available [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/#downloads). (Change the 'select platform' drop down to 'Source Code')